# Raster to polygon fails in ModelBuilder iteration

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator, error-999999, vectorization

I need to vectorize some rasters to polygons and to do so, I use the "Raster to Polygon" tool in ArcGIS Desktop 10.4. As there are many rasters, I use a iteration in ModelBuilder.

The output workspace is a Geodatabase and here comes the problem. When the model runs, the first iteration works fine. However, at the second iteration, the model fails at the "Raster to Polygon" tool. When I open the tool (right-click) to check it, I see that the system automatically added a .shp extension to my polygon. As the output workspace is a GDB, the tool fails.

This problem occurs for any source of rasters.

Here are some screenshots to help you understand.

The model and the tool before I click run:

[image: model and tool pre-run]

The error and the tool after it fails at second iteration:

[image: error and tool pos-run]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please always provide error messages as text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 1):

This is some sort of bug, I have come across it too. A solution is discussed on geonet here:

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/119427

Comment: It would be good to have that solution summarized or quoted here.